# Type interference in lambda expression

Tags: java, spring, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

Can you pls help to use type inference in the lambda expression? I have given sample code below, how to convert this as a lambda expression.

```
public <E> E convert(Object x, Object y) {        
    return (E) y;
}
```

Comment: Nothing in what you've written would be in any way clearer or simpler as a lambda.

Comment: Hi Louis, yes its simpler, wanted to understand how to convert this as lamda like BiFunction, do you have any idea?

Comment: I mean, you could have a lambda that does the same thing.  `(x, y) -> (E) y`.  You couldn't use that lambda to implement `convert`, and it wouldn't be _safer_, since that's an unsafe cast.

Comment: Why is there the parameter `Object x`? It isn't being used in the Method itself.

Comment: The method is already broken as it is promising to convert an arbitrary object to an arbitrary type, a promise it obviously can’t hold. What advantage do you expect from converting this broken method to a lambda expression?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following functional interface (a requirement for lambda expression):

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Converter {
    <E> E convert(Object x, Object y);
}
```

The method `convert` cannot be represented through a lambda expression since the target method is generic. The following code snippets of such lambda expressions are uncompilable.

- ```
  static <E> void foo() {
      Converter converter = (x, y) -> (E) y;                // doesn't compile
  }
  ```
- ```
  static void foo() {
      Converter converter = (x, y) -> (String) y;           // doesn't compile
  }
  ```

You must specify the generic type at the interface level:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Converter<E> {
    E convert(Object x, Object y);
}
```

Now the lambda expression usage is possible:

- ```
  static <E> void foo() {
      Converter<E> converter = (x, y) -> (E) y;             // compiles
  }
  ```
- ```
  static void foo() {
      Converter<String> converter = (x, y) -> (String) y;   // compiles
  }
  ```